# Can i make different variables of same values point to diffrent objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

I think this question might already have an answer here on SO, but I can't seem to find it. Please mark it as duplicate if you find an answer.

**I am not asking why, but how can I not let this happen?**

**I want `j` to have a diffrent `id` than  `i`.**

Say when i do,

```
>>> i = 6
>>> j = 6
>>> id(i) 
10919584
>>> id(j)
10919584 #I don't want this, I want j to point to a different object
```

So, I get what happens in the code above(Or at least I think I do), but my question is how can I prevent it?

> *I am asking it just out of curiosity, it may or may not have any practical usage or relevance.*

Comment: If you want a custom type where 6 may have multiple instantiations, can I suggest you create that? I tried `int("6")` and `int(6)` as would provide that ability in other languages, but I can't find it in python.

Comment: Python keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, so for any of these values, you will get this behaviour.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  thanks, I get the idea now. Please write it up as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit weirded by the possible uses of this; the option I've found:

```
class NoFixedInt(int):
  pass

a = NoFixedInt(6)
b = NoFixedInt(6)
c = NoFixedInt(6)

print id(a)
# 4485155368
print id(b)
# 4485155656
print id(c)
# 4485155728
```

Of course, I don't know if this works for you, as it has the issue that you have to cast everything, but it does the trick.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. As it was just out of curiosity, this solution is somewhat perfect as I can perform mathematical operations as well.