# Python Create Child objects in parent init with access to parent attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I want to create a parent object which creates its children and its children need to have access to one of the parent attributes.

I have found ways to create children inside a parent and ways to have access to one of the parent attributes, but no way to do both at the same time.

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number
        self.children = [Child(0), Child(2)]
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, number2):
        self.number2 = number2
    def printNumber(self):
        print(self.number+self.number2)
```

I expect:

```
par = Parent(3)
par.children[0].printNumber()
<3>
par.children[1].printNumber()
<5>
```

But, this will crash because par.children[0].number does not exist.

Comment: Why not create children from inside the child? Also you can call the parent using `super()`

Comment: Why not create children from inside the child? I am not sure of what you are proposing. If you propose to create multiple childs one at a time, I dislike this proposition. I would rather create a single parent object that automatically creates his children all in a single line of code. I think it makes sense.  Also you can call the parent using super(). I probably don't understand super(), but from my point of view, calling super() won't give me access to number unless I init parent inside the child's init function which I don't want to do. You probably can provide me with an example...

Comment: I feel like there's no pythonic way to do it.... I'm suprised as this would be possible  in C++ and makes a lot of sense to me

Comment: You can do it, but; you've overridden the init from the parent; hence you need to call it. `super().__init__` in your child init - or, define `__new__` in your parent, which creates the class. - Either way, you cant override a function in python and expect it to run on its own.

Comment: Adding `super().__init__` inside my child init will call the parent init function when i init a child which I don't want to do. I want to init the parent which in turns init a child that has access to its parent attributes. @JulianCamilleri

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to say that this does not seem an appropriate use of inheritance. Inheritance should be used to provide a multiple set of attributes and methods to different classes with things in common. Calling a child from a parent on initialization seems, a bit doubtful.

Still, I'm guessing there is a wider reason for this than this example. As such, I can offer a solution that does not require `Child` to use `super()` (as specified in the comments).

This solution has a caveat, though, and a big one. `self.number` becomes a class method and, as such, if a new `Parent` is instantiated with a diferent `number` value, it would change previously instantiated `Parent`s.

So here it goes:

```
class Parent():
    number = 0
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._change_number(number)
        self.children = [Child(0), Child(2)]

    @classmethod
    def _change_number(cls, number):
        cls.number = number

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, number2):
        self.number2 = number2
    def printNumber(self):
        print(self.number+self.number2)

par = Parent(3)
par.children[0].printNumber()
# 3
par.children[1].printNumber()
# 5
```

Again **be aware that number is a class variable!!**. Then, continuing the script with:

```
pir = Parent(5)  # Different instance
# changes the values in the previous instance par
par.children[0].printNumber()
# 5
par.children[1].printNumber()
# 7
```

I cannot see any other solution for this to work, as, without calling `super` from the `Child` there is no other way to initialize the `self.number` attribute if it is not a class one.

If you don't want this to happen, one option would be to calculate `self.number2` at `__init__` time. Then the value would be safely stored without more problem. In this case, `Child` would look like:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, number2):
        self.number2 = self.number+number2
    def printNumber(self):
        print(self.number2)
```

And a new instance would not affect the previous one:

```
par = Parent(3)
par.children[0].printNumber()
# 3
par.children[1].printNumber()
# 5
pir = Parent(5)  # Different instance
# DOES NOT change the values in the previous instance par
par.children[0].printNumber()
# 3
par.children[1].printNumber()
# 5
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer! Obviously, I dislike your first method because of the class variable. I agree with: "Inheritance should be used... with things in common."  That's what I'm looking for. number is common to Child(0) and Child(2) and we already know they exist if a parent is created. Inheritance is probably still not appropriate though... Finally, your last method won't work. In this situation, self.number does not exist inside the child init. We could pass the parent in argument to the child init though and it would work, BUT there would be two different number.

Comment: So, the second option does work (I did run it). `self.number` is still a class attribute, so it does exist in the `Child`. 
If you want to provide the two numbers to the `Child` during the `Parent` instantiation, then `Child` does not need to be a child of `Parent`.
Finally, I don't understand what you mean by "BUT there would be two different number", but if you are thinking memory wise, you should consider that same numbers do use [the same memory position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218730/can-i-make-different-variables-of-same-values-point-to-diffrent-objects/49219042).

Comment: Pasting your Child class with my Parent class and creating a Parent object pops me an AttributeError: "Child has no attribute number"... I agree with: "...Child does not need to be a child of Parent". I mean if you change the child number it won't change the parent number. @jaumebonet

Comment: sure... not with your `Parent` class.. but with the one I'm proposing in my answer.